# Will formatting C Drive wipe spanned drive on E/F?

Tags: windows, raid, format

I have Windows 7 on my SSD Drive, labeled C: I want to install Windows 8 but will formatting C drive wipe the spanned drive i have on the E/F Drives that i setup using disk management in windows 7?

I don't want to lose the data on my E/F drives but as they are a spanned volume will formatting the OS mess up the spanned volume?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

on the wizzard installation of windows 8 go to advanced options then you will find your three partions C,D,E (No F because of the DVD reader) so select only C and format it then install on it (NTFS) you will not lose your partition see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzI8xh5XXnw) and focus on the partition management step it is on **2 min 15 sec from the video**

```
the E partition will be D 
the F partition will be E
```